# Como posso armazenar os valores de token em um vetor?

Tags: c, string, struct

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char nome[20];
    char telefone[9];
}tipoCliente;

int main(){
    int n,q,i,j,cont;

    printf("Qtds:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&q);

    tipoCliente cliente[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d %s %s",&cliente[i].id,&cliente[i].nome,&cliente[i].telefone);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d %s %s\n",cliente[i].id,cliente[i].nome,cliente[i].telefone);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        j = atoi(cliente[i].telefone);
        cont = strlen(cliente[i].telefone);

        char* token = strtok(cliente[i].telefone,"-");

        while(token != NULL){
            printf("%s\n",token);
            token = strtok(NULL,"-");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como assim? Dê um exemplo para perceber o que é suposto ser feito...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concorda que `token` é uma variável do tipo `char *`? Para armazenar esse `tipo de dado` basta declarar um vetor de `char *`, note que daí esse *vetor de ponteiros* que você irá declarar servirá para armazenar ponteiros para **o início** dos *tokens*, e não como armazenamento para a cópia  deles.

Se precisar estritamente da cópia, você pode utilizar `strcpy()` juntamente com um vetor bidimensional para armazenar seus valores, pois `strcpy()` termina de copiar uma string quando ela encontra um `0` (código ASCII, não confundir com o caractere `'0'`). Por exemplo:

```
char s[100] = "908-123-3332";
```

A primeira chamada de `strtok()` retornará o *endereço* que tem valor diferente dos caracteres que estão presentes no argumento delimitadores, da função `strtok()`, que nesse meu exemplo é `'9'` neste exemplo o *endereço* `6`, na segunda chamada será o *endereço* `10`, na terceira `15` e na última `NULL`, e a variável `s[100]` será igual a

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+| '9' | '0' | '8' |  0  | '1' | '2' | '3' |  0  | '3' | '3' | '3' | '2' | 0 | ...
+   6  -  7  -  8  -  9  - 10  -  11 -  12 - 13  -  14 -  15 -  16 -  17 - 18 - ...
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

descontando as barras verticais que foram utilizadas somente como para dividir o vetor em cada uma de suas posições (endereços), que foram colocadas na linha de baixo.

Por exemplo, se você usar `strcpy(destino, 6)` onde `6` é o endereço, a variável `destino` será

`'9' | '0' | '8' | 0 | ...`

Se fosse `strcpy(destino, 11)` a string `destino` iria ser

`'2' | '3' | 0 | ...`

Baseado [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17104999/11452150) do SOen.